JavaScript function in Google spreadsheets to send QR codes to emails
We are planning for an event, to register you have to fill out a Google form, after filling it there is this function in the "Apps Script" of the spreadsheet that will generate and send a QR code to your email, I also did the trigger but the function didn't work, any thoughts on what went wrong?
The function:
function sendQrCodeEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var qrCodeUrlPrefix = ''https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x150&chl=';

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var email = data[i][2]; // third column is the email
    var name = data[i][1]; // second column is the name
    var qrCodeUrl = qrCodeUrlPrefix + encodeURIComponent(email);

    // Send Email with QR Code
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: email,
      subject: 'Your Event QR Code',
      htmlBody: 'Hello ' + name + ',<br><br>Thank you for registering. Please find your 
      QR code below.<br><img src="' + qrCodeUrl + '"><br>Best Regards,<br>Event Team'
    });
  }
}

Thank you for your time.

Look at the syntax highlighting on the line that sets qrCodeUrlPrefix. This is a great time to learn how to debug JS code effectively. Start by opening the browser and checking for errors. I'd also suggest changing your code editor to one which has syntax highlighting, so that errors like the string delimiter mentioned above become almost impossible to miss.

hey Rory, the QR image didn't load in the email, do you know why?

I think you have syntax error and some issue in the body tag.
 function sendQrCodeEmails() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      var qrCodeUrlPrefix = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x150&chl=';
    
      for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        var email = data[i][2]; // third column is the email
        var name = data[i][1]; // second column is the name
        var qrCodeUrl = qrCodeUrlPrefix + encodeURIComponent(email);
    
        // Send Email with QR Code
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: email,
          subject: 'Your Event QR Code',
          htmlBody: 'Hello ' + name + ',<br><br>Thank you for registering. Please find your QR code below.<br><img src="' + qrCodeUrl + '"><br>Best Regards,<br>Event Team'
        });
      }
    }


Okay, quick question, will it generate a unique QR code for each email?
I also test it but the image of the QR code did not load

@HaniAlmutlaq Yes, the functions generates unique QR code, but If the QR code image is not loading, it could be due to how the URL is constructed or how the image is being embedded in the email.

many thanks BugHunter

It takes a lot of time to send the QR, is this normal?

@HaniAlmutlaq Generating QR code it should go fast
